# What is the upper bound of this function?

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, exponential-function, upper-lower-bounds, set-partition

What is the upper bound of this quantity given $p_1+p_2+p_3=n$? (or $2p_1+p_2=n, p_3=0$ or $3p_1=n, p_2=p_3=0$)?

$$\frac{n!}{p_1!p_2!p_3!}\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{\binom{n}{2}-\binom{p_1}{2}-\binom{p_2}{2}-\binom{p_3}{2}}{2\beta(n)}\right)$$
where $n$ is positive integer, and $\beta(n)$ is a increasing function of $n$.

What I tried is to use Stirling formula to approximate the quantity thus obtained
$$\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi p_1}\left(\frac{p_1}{e}\right)^{p_1} \cdot \sqrt{2\pi p_2}\left(\frac{p_2}{e}\right)^{p_2} \cdot \sqrt{2\pi p_3}\left(\frac{p_3}{e}\right)^{p_3}} \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{\binom{n}{2}-\binom{p_1}{2}-\binom{p_2}{2}-\binom{p_3}{2}}{2\beta(n)}\right)$$

However I have no idea of how to proceed...

Hope anyone could help me out. Thanks in advance for any comment!